# How to translate templavoila template code to Fluid/Flux templating

Tags: typo3, fluid, fluid-layout, typo3-6.2.x, templavoila

I have a question regarding templavoila and Fluid. 
I migrated my website from TYPO3 4.7.x to TYPO3 6.2.x where the TYPO3 4.7.x uses Templavoila.
I now want to translate Templavoila code to Fluid/Flux code.
for example I have a TemplaVoila Flexible CE for dropdown:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<T3DataStructure>
    <meta type="array">
        <langDisable>1</langDisable>
    </meta>
    <ROOT type="array">
        <tx_templavoila type="array">
            <title>ROOT</title>
            <description>description</description>
        </tx_templavoila>
        <type>array</type>
        <el type="array">
            <field_dropdown_toggle type="array">
                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                    <title>Text Dropdown Toggle</title>
                    <sample_data type="array">
                        <numIndex index="0">Style</numIndex>
                    </sample_data>
                    <eType>input</eType>
                    <proc type="array">
                        <HSC type="integer">1</HSC>
                    </proc>
                    <TypoScript type="NULL"></TypoScript>
                </tx_templavoila>
                <TCEforms type="array">
                    <config type="array">
                        <type>input</type>
                        <size>200</size>
                        <eval>trim</eval>
                    </config>
                    <label>Text Dropdown Toggle</label>
                </TCEforms>
            </field_dropdown_toggle>
            <field_dropdown_menu type="array">
                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                    <title>Dropdown-Menü</title>
                    <sample_data type="array">
                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                    </sample_data>
                    <eType>ce</eType>
                    <TypoScript>
10 = RECORDS
10.source.current = 1
10.tables = tt_content
                                        </TypoScript>
                    <oldStyleColumnNumber type="integer">0</oldStyleColumnNumber>
                </tx_templavoila>
                <TCEforms type="array">
                    <config type="array">
                        <type>group</type>
                        <internal_type>db</internal_type>
                        <allowed>tt_content</allowed>
                        <size>5</size>
                        <maxitems>200</maxitems>
                        <minitems>0</minitems>
                        <multiple>1</multiple>
                        <show_thumbs>1</show_thumbs>
                    </config>
                    <label>Dropdown-Menü</label>
                </TCEforms>
            </field_dropdown_menu>
            <field_dropdown_header type="array">
                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                    <title>Überschrift</title>
                    <sample_data type="array">
                        <numIndex index="0"></numIndex>
                    </sample_data>
                    <eType>none</eType>
                    <TypoScript>
                        10 = TEXT
                        10.data = register:tx_templavoila_pi1.parentRec.header
                    </TypoScript>
                    <preview></preview>
                </tx_templavoila>
            </field_dropdown_header>
            <field_dropdown_header_layout type="array">
                <type>attr</type>
                <tx_templavoila type="array">
                    <title>Header Typ</title>
                    <eType>none</eType>
                    <TypoScript>
                        10 = TEXT
                        10 {
                            data = register:tx_templavoila_pi1.parentRec.header_layout
                            wrap = dropdown-header h|
                        }
                    </TypoScript>               
                    <proc type="array">
                        <HSC type="integer">1</HSC>
                    </proc>
                </tx_templavoila>
            </field_dropdown_header_layout>
        </el>
    </ROOT>
</T3DataStructure>
```

and I would like to transform this code to flux like this:

```
<flux:field.input name="textToggle" label="Text Dropdown Toggle" />
```

Is there a documentation how to transform?

[here is the screenshot of templavoila](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NWC38.png)

How do I get exactly like using flux/fluid. I can get Input field but cannot get dropdown-menu.
Can anyone please suggest me what to do.
If my question is not clear, please let me  know and I will try to explaiin it again.
I would appreciate your Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension `sf_tv2fluidge` (I'm the author) only supports migration of TV flexible content elements to GridElements. Since you are using flux, the migration will not work with `sf_tv2fluidge`.

You could try to use the [fork](https://github.com/techniConcept/tv2fluid) of `sf_tv2fluidge` from techniConcept. They support flux, but require fluidpages and fluidcontent.